# get a text file using php and send the string to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, string

Ok, what I am trying to do is make a javascript loop of images, but first I have to get a list of the images. In javascript there is no way to directly grab this text file... http://www.ssd.noaa.gov/goes/east/tatl/txtfiles/ft_names.txt but it can be done eaisly in php, I am currently gettung the txt file using php, but the javascript cannot read the variable. How can I make javascript be able to read this variable. Here is what I have...

```
<?php
$file = "http://www.ssd.noaa.gov/goes/east/tatl/txtfiles/ft_names.txt"; //Path to your *.txt file
$contents = file($file);
$string = implode($contents);
echo $string;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function prnt() {
        var whatever = "<?= $string ?>";
        alert(whatever);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What output are you getting right now?  I assume you're calling prnt() somewhere?

Comment: Do you have short tags enabled?

Comment: what are the contents of the text? are there line breaks and so on?

Comment: @Doug nothing, there is no alert box, but if I create just a regular variable in php eg. $string = "Ok" and the don't add anything to it, it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure your $string is non-empty and the problem isn't occurring at the PHP stage?

Comment: @Vibhu - That could be the issue, how would you make it a pure string, I have tried a few things, but they have not worked.

Comment: Also, instead of file() followed by implode(), why not just use file_get_contents()?  http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: @Doug - The string is definetly not empty, because when I echo it, it is printed perfectly onto the screen.

Comment: you could try replacing line break characters with spaces (line break characters are \n and \r)

Comment: @Vibhu - Going to try that now...

Comment: You probably have an error due to just printing out some random string into your javascript code.  Try outputting the string with special characters replaced using html_special_chars() or something like that.  You are probably just not seeing the errors and it's just failing silently.

Comment: Thanks, I will work with these solutions and let you know the result.

Comment: Resolved with the following code... $string = file($filenam, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$str = implode($string);

Answer (score 0):

You can use echo or print to write to the page in PHP.

```
var whatever = "<?php echo $string; ?>";
```

Although, if the file has line breaks in it, you will need to remove those.

Comment: That did not work for me either. Btw I did not state this, but I do not want to print the string to the page.

Comment: What do you want then? JavaScript cannot directly read a variable from PHP. It has to be parsed when the page is loaded or you need to get it via AJAX.

Comment: I want the text file located at http://www.ssd.noaa.gov/goes/east/tatl/txtfiles/ft_names.txt or any other url I choose to be loaded into a javascript var somehow.

Comment: You should probably use AJAX then.

Comment: Is it possible to read a txt file from outside your domain name in AJAX, I have read that it is not.

Comment: It's possible, but it isn't easy. I didn't realize you were on a different domain. You should probably stick with printing the value into a JavaScript variable. `var whatever = "<?php echo preg_replace( "/\r?\n/", "\\n", addslashes( $string ) ); ?>";`

Answer (score 0):

Make it a bit more interesting: go ahead and split the fields and use JSON encoding. It should read directly in javascript without needing to call JSON.parse() on the client.

```
<?php
$lines = file_get_contents('http://...');
$lines = explode("\n",trim($lines));
foreach ($lines as &$line) {
    $line = preg_split('/,? /',$line);
}
$js = json_encode($lines);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dar = <?php echo $js; ?>;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You should also consider using a local proxy to cache the results of that file if you plan to run this frequently and especially if you are going to serve it up on a public web server somewhere. Store the file locally as "noaa_data.txt" and have a second script on a cron job (12 hours or something):

```
<?php 
file_put_contents("/var/www/noaa_data.txt",file_get_contents("http://www.ssd.noaa.gov/goes/east/tatl/txtfiles/ft_names.txt"));
?>
```